# Open a new window on response with pdf attachment

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

```
jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager2",{caption:"Save All",title:"Save & Create Receipt",onClickButton:function () { 
      var s; 
      s = jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
      alert("selected"); 
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:'http://localhost:3000/order/receipt',
        data: {ids: s},
      });
    }});
```

With above code, I'm able to submit data to server and the on server side it will generate a pdf as attachment, now I want to view the pdf on response via a new window/tab on browser.

Anyway to do it?

thanks,
lupind

Answer (score 1):

If you return a URL to the just generated PDF then you can call window.open with that URL. But I wouldn't use an Ajax call if you want to open a new window to display the PDF anyway. In this case I would either:

- Use Javascript's window.open passing
  through the data in the URL to the
  page that generates the PDF and let
  it output to the browser's window
  (but it might be too much data in the
  URL)
- Create a special form to hold
  the data from your page and submit
  that form. This special form would
  have a target attribute set
  (target="_blank") to open it in a new
  window/tab.

For me, using two HTTP calls for one result (the generation and viewing of a PDF) is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) to open a new window with a specified URL. Be careful, though, only to do this when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/610641-file-download-ajax).

Use an `iframe` with `visibility:hidden`, then change the `iframe` location to a downloadable file in javascript on the success callback.

```
 var iFrame = document.getElementById('hiddenIFrame');
 iFrame.src = theurlThatWillProduceTheFile;
```